# Getting operationId from OpenAPI based on path

Tags: javascript, openapi

Is there any simple to use Javascript library that is capable of loading OpenAPI specification and providing information about operation based on path and HTTP method?

Example

```
const theTool = magicLibrary.loadOpenAPISpec(spec);
const operationInfo = theTool.findOperation({method: 'GET', path: '/resource/1234'});
const operationId = operationInfo.operationId;
```

Please note that path can contain path parameter and query parameters so the tool has to really check against OpenAPI specification and provide correct operation.

Comment: Check out JavaScript / Node.js parsers for OpenAPI, such as [swagger-js](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js) the ones listed in https://openapi.tools/#parsers. You can probably implement what you need by using one of these parsers.

Comment: I already did that by simply parsing on YAML->JSON tree which proved to be 40 LoC instead of using some libraries. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest thing was to read YAML and reduces `/paths` as entries and build simple trie from entries.
This was around 40LoC and serves purpose and it's performant, predictable and under control.

Comment: Would you be willing to share this code?